# Convert string to TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#, silverlight, timezone

Hey everyone so I currently have a silverlight program where I am receiving the timezone from a product but it is currently being saved in a string format. I am needing to convert the given time from the user to their UTC time using their timezone. I've done some research and found out that TimeZoneInfo has a method called ConvertTime(DateTime dt, TimeZoneInfo timeZone) and it will convert the date time into UTC based off the users time zone. The issue that I am running into is this. This is the following code that I have:

```
public DateTime GetUtclocal(string timeZoneId, DateTime dt)
{
     return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString(timeZoneInfo);
{
```

problem is that I have is that I get an error saying 'System.TimeZoneInfo' does not contain a definition for 'FromSerializedString' 
Not sure if I am missing something obvious but any help would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your timeZoneInfo string value?

Comment: It can vary from anything from US Mountain Time all the way to W. Australia Standard Time.. I've tried making a TimeZoneInfo tzf and seeing if the method was available in there but still nothing

Comment: Your string is not following the correct format would be my guess.

Comment: Well it's not really that the string is not in the correct format the method FromSerializedString from TimeZoneInfo doesn't contain that definition.. So I am trying to figure out how I can get this method to work

Comment: Actually in fact going to the definition for TimeZoneInfo in visual studios shows that the method FromSerializedString doesn't isn't even inside the definition.. Maybe it's an older version of TimeZoneInfo? Not really sure